# How to remove few decimal places in R?

Tags: r

I want to keep only the first 2 decimal places in each number in a numeric vector. For instance, how can I do following in R?

```
> x <- c(95.45000, 97.53333)

> keep_the_first_two_decimal_places_only(x)
> [1] 95.45 97.53
```

Note, that I don't want to just `print` the less number of decimal places, I want to actually remove the extra digits.

Comment: `round(x, digits = 2)`

Comment: Just for you to know another option `sprintf("%.2f", x)`

Comment: Or maybe `trunc_digits <- function(x,digits){e <- 10^digits; trunc(x*e) / e}` if you don't want rounding.